# GData, OAuth and iPhone - Maintaining security when dealing with Access Tokens

Tags: iphone, oauth, gdata

I'd like to get an OAuth access token client-side (iPhone) and send the access token back to my server to make gdata requests on behalf of the user.  Basically my question is, is this safe?  Couldn't someone sniff the connection and pull the access token out and use it maliciously?

Google allows you to authenticate 'unregistered' applications by using 'anonymous' as the consumer key and secret in HMAC-SHA1 signature mode, which is what I'm doing.  I'm then passing the acquired access token server-side to do my data manipulation.  It works which is great, but I'm having security concerns about the solution.

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your server secure? Are you issuing requests using https?  Also, is registering to get an actual consumer key/secret out of the question? An access token is only good for the consumer key/secret that generated it.  If you were to register, that would add another level of security (being that your consumer key/secret would only be known to you) but I would always suggest that communication from your app to your server should be done over a secure connection.

Comment: I am using Google App Engine as the server, so I believe it's secure.  I suppose I could do the authentication server-side through a web-view to avoid having to pass the token back directly.  I am not using https right now... not even sure if GAE supports it, but I will check.  Doing the authentication server-side should also let me register the domain with Google and let me use a consumer key+secret, I think.